# Devise Controller neglects '+' character

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I have written an API in the Devise Registrations controller to check if user with given email id exists or not?

```
def check_user
  user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
  if user
    render json: { success: true, status: 200} and return
  else
    render json: { success: false, status: 200} and return
  end
end
```

Devise controller somehow strips the '+' character in the parameter.
ie when I hit , `/check_user?email=tester+12343@mailer.com`, the parameter that gets to the controller is , `Parameters: {"email"=>"soorajs 12343@qburst.com"}`, is this due to any bad configuration of devise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not devise, it is rails. `+` means encoded space in query strings. If you want literal plus, then you should encode it as `%2B`.

Alternatively, you can use POST requests and send params in request body. No escaping is needed there. Although using POST for an obvious query is a faux-pas.